# Objective-C Deleted UILocalNotification Still Comes after deletion

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I create local push notifications with a notID and after that, in deletion process i delete it with the following code block;

```
NSString *myIDToCancel = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"m%@", object.reminderID];
UILocalNotification *notificationToCancel=nil;

for(UILocalNotification *aNotif in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications]) {
                            if([[aNotif.userInfo objectForKey:@"notID"] isEqualToString:myIDToCancel]) {
                                notificationToCancel=aNotif;
                                    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:notificationToCancel];
//                                break;
                            }
                        }
```

I commented the break; because there can be more than 1 notification with same ID -like 4 times a day notification with 6 hours between have same notID- so i can check all notifications before going out of the for loop.

It used to work perfect, but now it is not. While debugging i can see it checks and cancels one by one every notification, but after that local notification fires up even its cancelled.

EDIT: i also checked the scheduledLocalNotifications with:
`NSArray *localNotifications = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications];`

code block and it shows 0 elements after deletion, but it still fires up.

Comment: have you checked list of your notifications after cancelling? are they still in queue?

Comment: @AlexandrKolesnik yes, it shows 0 elements in array as i got it with the following code:

'NSArray *localNotifications = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications];'